# Django Rest Framework function view post not working

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

So I am trying to serve a static file through a simple Django Rest framework function view. It gives me 200 code but doesn't download the file.

Here is the code :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def download_file(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = MySerializer(data=request.data)
        filename = 'file.xlsx'
        file_full_path = "src/{0}".format(filename)

        with open(file_full_path, 'rb') as f:
            file = f.read()
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type="application/xls")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename={0}".format(filename)
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_full_path)
        return response
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

What am  I doing wrong here?

Comment: hi your code is working fine check in MySerializer :  do you need this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to download file with a **`HTTP POST`** method, I don't think it's a nice way. So try **`HTTP GET`** for downloading. If you wish to provide extra arguments (payload in POST method), you could do it  using `Query Parameter` as `/api/end/point/?param=value1&param2=value2`.
So, try the following snippet,

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def download_file(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        filename = 'file.xlsx'
        file_full_path = "src/{0}".format(filename)

        with open(file_full_path, 'rb') as f:
            file = f.read()
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type="application/xls")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename={0}".format(filename)
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_full_path)
        return response
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```